# findFragmentByTag returns null in Activity at some places

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know this question has been asked so many times but I have tried every thing which was answered
like

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

used `fragmentTransaction.replace`

my problem is when I use findFragmentByTag, it works at one place and does not work at other place.

I am not getting where I am doing wrong because findFragmentByTag return fragment in R.id.action_clean case but does not work in R.id.action_cart case.

my code is

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
           case R.id.action_cart: // don't work in this case
               if (Cart.getProductCount(this) > 0) {
                   if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CartFragment.class.getName()) != null) {
                       if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CartFragment.class.getName()).isVisible()) {
                           Log.v("visible","visible");
                       }
                       Log.v("visible2","not null");
                       Toast.makeText(this, "Cart is not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   else{
                       changeFragment(new CartFragment());
                   }
               }else{
                   Toast.makeText(this,"Cart is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               break;
            case R.id.action_login:
                changeFragment(new LoginFragment());
               // Toast.makeText(this,"login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_signup:
                changeFragment(new UserDetailFragment());
                //Toast.makeText(this,"sign up",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_clean: // work here
                if(Cart.clearCart(this)){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"All items has been removed from Cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateCartCount();
                    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CartFragment.class.getName()) != null
                            && getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CartFragment.class.getName()).isVisible()) {
                        removeFragment(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CartFragment.class.getName()));
                    }
                }else Toast.makeText(this,"Cart can not be cleaned",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and here is the changeFragment

```
 @Override
    public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment, CustomDictionary... dictionary) {
        FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if (dictionary != null && dictionary.length > 0) {
            for (CustomDictionary dic : dictionary) {
                bundle.putString(dic.getKey(),dic.getValue());
            }
        }
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment,fragment.getClass().getName()) // tag
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
                .commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    }
```

removeFragment()

```
@Override
    public void removeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment)
                .commit();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
```

Comment: you're calling 2 different methods. In the action_clean case you're calling removeFragment and in action_cart you call changeFragment. What are the differences in the implementations?

Comment: now check, I have edited the question

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is the Fragment just not going anywhere? Have you done a Log.v printout to make sure that the class names are the same going in and out?

The other question: If there is more than one instance of that Fragment that exists at the same time it may be removing one that you cannot see. Perhaps doing a workflow to make sure that there is only the one in existence is a good idea. Giving a Log printout in the Fragments onCreateView() and onDestroy() overrides might give some more information.

Answer (score 0):

You used different name for tags...
you assigned tag by

```
fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

And call it by

```
CartFragment.class.getName()
```

So just use one of them for both process setting and getting by tag.
**P.S.  You set tag when you call addToBackStack !**

**----- Update:**

I would suggest to iterate all fragments you have in backstack by:

```
for (Fragment fragment : getFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            try {
                Log.v(TAG,"fragment:"+fragment.getTag()+", isVisible:"+fragment.isVisible());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            }
        }
```

Then it will be clear what is the tag of fragment to call if exists :-)
use **getSupportFragmentManager** instead of **getFragmentManager** when call from activity.

Comment: changeFragment is generic method which will open all fragments, when ever I want to change fragment I call it and pass the fragments ..

Comment: you set tag with fragment.getClass().getSimpleName() and query it by CartFragment.class.getName() ...

Comment: I have checked it by replacing getSimpleName() to getName() still not working